# Failure after upgrading to Android Studio Preview 1.5

Tags: android-studio

After upgrading to current (canary channel) Android Studio Preview 1.5, I get an erroneous error message complaining about not having Gradle v2.10 in use.

**Error message:**

```
Error:Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Development\Google\MyGitHub\Cinebox2\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip
<a href="fixGradleVersionInWrapper">Fix Gradle wrapper and re-import project</a><br><a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a>
```

**Here is my gradle-wrapper.properties file:**

```
#Fri Jan 15 11:54:39 EST 2016
  distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  distributionPath=wrapper/dists
  zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
  zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
  distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

How can I resolve ... I would love to continue developing and testing!

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by *NOT* specifying use of gradle wrapper in the configuration of Android Studio.  To remedy this use the following steps:

1. Select `*File->Settings*`
2. Expand "`Build, Execution, Deployment`"
3. Select "`Gradle`"
4. In Project-level settings, select "`Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)`"

If you use Offline Work, ensure that you download Gradle 2.10 and place it in the indicated directory (`xxx\.gradle\wrapper\dists`)